# how to fetch data from firebase database on firebaserecycleradapter click

Tags: java, android, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

adapter

```
firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<AllUsers, UsersViewHolder>(options) {
        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull UsersViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull AllUsers model) {
            holder.setName(model.getName());
            holder.setStatus(model.getStatus());

            final String user_id = getRef(position).getKey();
            final String user_name = getRef(position).

            holder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Chat.class);
                    intent.putExtra("Recievers_Id", user_id);
                    intent.putExtra("Recievers_Name", user_name);

                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });

        }

        @Override
        public UsersViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.all_users_layout, parent, false);

            return new UsersViewHolder(view);
        }
    };
    mUsersList.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);

    return rootView;
}
```

i do know that .getkey(); returns the parent data... but inside the parent i have a child which is "Name" and i want to fetch that... how do i achieve this

Screenshot of database - https://ibb.co/mBKZLd

Comment: If you are interested, **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49383687/how-can-i-retrieve-data-from-firebase-to-my-adapter/49384849)** is how you can retrieve data from a Firebase Realtime database and display it in a `RecyclerView` using `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter`.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");

reference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
 @Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
   for(DataSnapshot datas: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
       String keys=datas.getKey();
       String name=datas.child("Name").getValue().toString();
      }
 }
  @Override
public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
    }
 });
```

First snapshot is at `Users` then iterate and get the key and the Name

Comment: I think the OP wants to know how to do that inside the Firebase UI component FirebaseRecyclerAdapter

Comment: what do you have in the item?! Also add the above inside the onclicklistener